# in Perl, how do i write regex matched string

Tags: perl

I want to write $1 on other line for replacement;

```
my $converting_rules = +{
    '(.+?)' => '$1',
};

my $pre     = $converting_rule_key;
my $post    = $converting_rules->{$converting_rule_key};
#$path_file =~ s/$pre/$post/; // Bad... 
$path_file =~ s/$pre/$1/; // Good!
```

On Bad, $1 is recognized as a string '$1'.
But I wqnt to treat it matched string.
I have no idea what to do...plz help me!

Comment: Then don't wrap it in single quotes?

Comment: @Wooble: OP probably wants the value of `$1` determined by the `s///` operator, not the value when `$converting_rules` is defined.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that `s/$pre/$post/` interpolates the variables `$pre` and `$post`, but will not recursively interpolate anything in them that happens to look like a variable.  So you want to add an extra `eval` to the replacement, with the `/ee` flag:

```
$path_file =~ s/$pre/$post/ee;
```

Comment: @ikegami Thanks. Fixed, but now I need to do more research.

Comment: Without /e: Substitutes with the result of `qq/$post/`. With /e: Substitutes with the result of `$post`. With /ee: Substitutes with the result of `eval($post)`.

Comment: I see.  So `s/PATTERN/$var/` and `s/PATTERN/$var/e` are (almost/exactly?) equivalent, but `s/PATTERN/reverse $var/` and `s/PATTERN/reverse $var/e` might result in replacements `"reverse filename"` and `"emanelif"` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = '$1.00';
print qq/$x/;
```

prints `$1.00`, so it's no surprise that

```
$x = '$1.00';
s/(abc)/$x/;
```

substitutes with `$1.00`.

What you have there is a template, yet you did nothing to process this template. [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aInterpolate) can handle such templates.

```
use String::Interpolate qw( interpolate );
$rep = '$1';
s/$pat/ interpolate($rep) /e;
```